# Tensorflow shows errors after importing using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, debian

I installed Tensorflow using pyenv. But whenever i import it gives me this error.I am using Debian in raspberry pi4.My python version is 3.7.12 and tensorflow version is 2.5.0.

'''  pi@raspberrypi:~/project $ python
Python 3.7.12 (default, Mar 22 2022, 14:27:41)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow
> > > RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "", line 1, in 
> > > File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py", line 41, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
> > > File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py", line 40, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python.eager import context
> > > File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 37, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
> > > File "/home/pi/.pyenv/versions/3.7.12/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/pywrap_tf_session.py", line 23, in 
> > > from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tf_session import *
> > > ImportError: SystemError: <built-in method **contains** of dict object at 0x7f741852d0> returned a result with an error set
> > > '''

Answer (score 0):

The error message tries to say that `Tensorflow` needs a recent version of `numpy`. So,try to upgrade numpy `pip3 install --upgrade numpy`

Comment: I edited the answer to explain briefly why the answer solves the issue.